# FCM React.js/Node npm: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'toJSON' of object 'Error'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, firebase-cloud-messaging, node-modules

I am trying to get FCM working on our company's client React.js web app and after reviewing the Firecasts on the subject and finding and following [this Medium tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1) on using firebase cloud messaging with React.js, it keeps erroring on app boot. If I comment out the initialization for Firebase, the app boots without issue.

I used node npm to install the firebase module and created the required push-notification.js and firebase-messaging-sw.js files outlined in the tutorial. I have tried narrowing down the config var to just the messagingSenderId and that did resolve the error. I am not sure what else to try as this is my first time working with Firebase and am quite new to their libraries and SDK's.

Below I will give as much code context as possible. For liability reasons, I cannot display out all the context code but will try to produce the relevant snippets and import statements. In addition, all keys, passwords, or other identifiers that are sensitive will be removed as well.

index.js file code:

```
import { initializeFirebase, askForPermissionToReceiveNotifications } from './push-notification';
ReactDOM.render(<ReduxApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
initializeFirebase();
askForPermissionToReceiveNotifications();
```

push-notification.js file code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

export const initializeFirebase = () => {
  var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "authDomain",
    databaseURL: "databaseURL",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "storageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export const askForPermissionToReceiveNotifications = async () => {
  try {
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    await messaging.requestPermission();
    const token = await messaging.getToken();
    console.log('user token:', token);

    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('onMessage: ', payload);
})
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js file code:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');
firebase.initializeApp({
   apiKey: "apiKey",
   authDomain: "authDomain",
   databaseURL: "databaseURL",
   projectId: "projectId",
   storageBucket: "storageBucket",
   messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId"
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

On app boot and with the `import firebase from 'firebase';` statement active (not commented out), I get: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property 'toJSON' of object 'Error'`

When I comment out the `import firebase from 'firebase';` statement and the function calls in index.js, the app boots with no errors.

If you need more context to assist with this problem, let me know what you need/want to see and I will add it in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that was done on purpose because it prevents authentication upon error. I would guess that it's your actual token value, not variable, that's wrong. Good luck :)

Comment: After testing, I found that if the `import firebase from 'firebase';` statement is present, it stops executing there and throws this `TypeError`. no logging will output.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the TypeError went away when I used this type of import:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';
```

There are still other bugs in this solution. But the light at the end of the tunnel is now visible.